# Key Value pair appears in LocalStorage, but doesn't persist after refresh despite having JSON stringify/setItem/etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I built a Todo application, and it works smoothly, minus the fact that the localStorage won't persist beyond a refresh. The localStorage commands formerly worked when I had fewer event handlers, but now it seems like somewhere along the way, the storage gets wiped. I've tried the basic solutions I've seen here, but there seems to be something unique making the error. Here are my save/get functions:

Save:

```
const saveLocalTodos = () => {
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
};
```

Get:

```
const getLocalTodos = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
  } else {
    let localTodo = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos))
    );
    setTodos(localTodo);
  }
};
```

Effectively, the process saves by setting the "todos" item as the stringified array todos (which works and shows up in local storage when a new todo is added/completion status is changed/item is starred/etc.). The useState function is as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
  filteredTodosHandler();
  saveLocalTodos();
}, [todos, status, starredToggle]);
```

So like I said, called when the todos array changes, the clickable status filter is changed, or the starred checkbox is clicked. None of that breaks the localStorage. Now here's the useEffect for getLocalTodos:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getLocalTodos();
}, []);
```

If I understand correctly, an empty array roughly means that it's called when the page is refreshed. The issue is that when I refresh, I always get an empty array. I've tried adding "window." at the beginning of localStorage function calls, adding e.preventDefault onto the event handlers involved in the saveLocalTodos cases, and ensuring that I'm turning the array into a stringified object. Nothing seems to work. I have a copy of the application in a GitHub repository and hosted via Firebase if that would add additional insight.

Comment: does localstorage completely get wiped/empty on refresh or just empty array as `[]` ?

Comment: It becomes an empty array with the key "todos". I was wondering about that myself, it'd seem as if the issue is *maybe* with the error handling in the if statement?

Comment: then `useEffect` is changing the localstorage on initial render when you refresh. check the dependency array of `useEffect`

Comment: Sounds good Emre. I’ll report back to you after work when I can get back to ironing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Do you define todos like this?

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
```

And does the loading block

```
useEffect(() => {
  getLocalTodos();
}, []);
```

goes after the saving block

```
useEffect(() => {
  filteredTodosHandler();
  saveLocalTodos();
}, [todos, status, starredToggle]);
```

in your code?

If so, then the saving effect `saveLocalTodos();` would be called before the loading effect `getLocalTodos()`, when page reloads and it would save the default value of [] from useState([]); to the local storage which is then loaded by the loading effect.
That's how it might get wiped out.

To test it try to to switch the order of `useEffect` blocks. Also add some logging to check the order in which these blocks are run.

In case that works you should still change the design, it's really bad if the order of declaration of `useEffect` is important, someone (even you) might later change it and reintroduce the problem.

Comment: The todos state is set as: `const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);` I hadn't yet tried logging the useState order, but I will try that. Thank you

Comment: changed null for []

Comment: As suggestion of design change - you can just load todos before calling useState like this `useState(getLocalTodos())` and modify getLocalTodos to return the result value instead of calling setTodos(localTodo);

Comment: When I log it, it looks like on refresh, everything is called. This thing looks like it's going to be a massive mess. I need to go to work now, but there's a lot that'll need to be fixed evidently. Hopefully, it's just a matter of rewriting some useEffect statements so that I don't have a loop where it seems to go saveTodos -> getTodos -> saveTodos on refresh. I don't know if the architecture was faulty when the instructor made it, but it sure is now.

Comment: It does not look like too big of a mess. I guess the save block would be called twice on page reloading. Just remove the loading effect `useEffect(() => { getLocalTodos(); }, []);` and load directly when you call useState

Comment: It appears as if the issue is tied to my forms being defaulted following page refresh. Even though I added preventDefault to the event handlers, it seems like the page refresh wipes the state of both the starred and sortby properties

Comment: When the page is refreshed, all data, associated with the document gets erased. That includes all form data and javascript variables, but excludes explicit storages, cookies, caches, which retain data. So you have to either load your data before rendering forms, or block the saving of the form data, before the data is loaded. That said, does your application have a server side as permanent storage? Local storage is a good way to store unimportant data between sessions, but must not be used as a permanent storage of important user's data for many reasons.

Comment: The choice to have local storage-based data storage was more so because the project's scope is just an unauthenticated, single-user utility. So like each user has their own self-contained copy of the application they can use, but there isn't a login needed. So I don't know what a solution would be using the current model. Authentication and database storage is an option, I suppose, but it seems like overkill for the project's scope.